# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, rest

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/me/Downloads/Student-API-2.0/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into Student values(17,"Nil","aj@gmail.com"); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Nil" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Student values(17,"Nil","aj@gmail.com") [42122-197]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Nil" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Student values(17,"Nil","aj@gmail.com") [42122-197]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the columns in your sql sentence to ensure it doesn't mismatch a value with a column name.

```
insert into Student(column1, column2, column3) values(17,'Nil','aj@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering